# How to enable Bluetooth in i3wm in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, i3-wm

I want to connect my Bluetooth keyboard to Ubuntu when I login in i3wn. The keyboard can connect to Ubuntu when I login in Unity. In I3wm, when I type

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
```

The server starts and works well. I tried `bluetooth-wizard`, it just wouldn't find any devices. So what should I do?

Answer (score 8):

I found `blueman-manager` to be really great for quickly adding bluetooth devices. Maybe this can work for you, if you haven't found a solution yet?